# Force multithreading in select query? [Oracle or Sql-Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading, select, oracle11g

I have a select query that calls a function three times [of course each time with diff input col]. I'm noticing that the execution time [multiple rows] is 8 seconds vs 3 seconds when I invoke the function once. It makes sense, since the work load is tripled.

**ASK:**
Is it possible to hint the DB server to force multithread since they are 3 different independent columns?

I tried extracting results separately and joining them. Even they don't seem to create any type of parallelism, neither in SQL-Server or Oracle. Using SS syntax below.

```
select top 200 dbo.CALC_DURATION (Col1, Col2 , 'PP', 553, '', 'N', 'H'),
               dbo.CALC_DURATION (Col3, Col4 , 'PP', 553, '', 'N', 'H'),
               dbo.CALC_DURATION (Col5, Col6 , 'PP', 553, '', 'N', 'H') 
from NNMP265_ISS;
```

[image]
Function snippet above:

Comment: I doubt it's possible as CALC_DURATION is a scalar function. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134453/sql-not-engaging-parallelism-for-extremely-large-query

Comment: Can you include the code for the function? People might have ideas how it could be done in other ways that don't prevent parallelism.

Comment: Sure, thx. The function computes work hours by prioritizing 2 sets of data and then precisely calculates the working hours between start and end time. Attaching a screenshot in the main question as I couldn't fit the program here.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer with respect to Oracle: In Oracle parallism works with respect to finding (and inserting/modifying) rows. That means that parallel execution will help you find the results - not on plsql routines you execute on them.

Now here comes the tricky part: If the result of a PL/SQL routine is needed to build the result set (e.g. WHERE my_function(col1) > 3) it will profit from parallelism; if the routine is only applied to "beautify" the final result (e.g.  SELECT my_function(col3) it will not because it will not happen within the PX Executor.

You can try to trick the optimiser to execute your function in parallel by using materialize hints or by hiding under multiple levels of sub queries but I would seriously recommend not to do that. The behaviour of the optimizer is not stable even across minor version and might suddenly behave completely different after an update. This is asking for many unhappy Monday-after-Patchday.

The best way to solve your problem is to avoid applying PL/SQL to a result set and rewrite your query to use plain SQL only. Under Oracle this is especially true since you avoid the costs of switching between SQL and PL/SQL contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem like you. I have a scalar function to calculate the car route between two points

So the process time is linear, one calculation take 8 ms but 1000 calculations need 8 seconds.

I couldnt make the paralelism work in postgre sql so I make a C# function to send multiple request to db using 4 thread I actually reduce the total time from 8 seconds to 2 seconds.

You can see a reference to my code here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155253/splitting-a-list-of-numbers-into-multiple-lists

Focus on the function `routeParallelGeneration` where `route_source` have the info need it to calculate the route.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Juan.